# Haskell Lazy Evaluation and Rewriting

Tags: haskell

Function Definitions:

```
first_threes :: [Int]                     -- first three numbers repeated
first_threes = 1:2:3:first_threes         -- th.1

take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]                 -- take
take 0 _ = []                             -- t.1
take n (x:xs) = x : (take (n - 1) xs)     -- t.2

sum :: [Int] -> Int                       -- summation of an Int list
sum [] = 0                                -- s.1
sum (x:xs) = x + (sum xs)                 -- s.2
```

I need to rewrite the statement below by using the definitions of the functions above. I need to obtain the answer 9. I need to justify each solution using 'Lazy Evaluation'.

```
Hugs_Main> my sum (my take 5 first_threes)
9
```

I am trying to work out 20 solutions which obtain 9 as the answer. Below are my first 10 solutions but I cannot think of anything else. Can anyone help out?

My first 10 solutions:

```
my_sum (my_take 5 first_threes)
my_sum (my_take 5 (1:2:3:first_threes))
my_sum (my_take 5 (1:2:first_threes))
my_sum (my_take 5 (2:first_threes))
my_sum (my_take 4 (3:first_threes))
my_sum (1:2:3:(my_take 2 (first_threes)))
my_sum (1:2:(my_take 3 (first_threes)))
my_sum (1:(2:my_take 3 (3:first_threes)))
my_sum (1:(my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes)))
my_sum (1:(my_take 4 (2:first_threes)))
```

Comment: In the future please format your code so others can read it more easily.  Also, are you just asking us to interpret your code?  Why can't you just copy and paste each of your ten evaluations into an interpreter like GHCi and see the answer for yourself?

Comment: there are literally infinitely many ways to represent even `first_threes`

Comment: also there is stuff like `4+5` which is also the same as `my_sum (my_take 5 first_threes)` and a valid substitution for it. You will have to be a bit more precise

Comment: @NiklasB. I have updated the question it should more precise and understandable.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I have updated the question it should more precise and understandable.

Comment: First few steps probably go something like this: `sum (take 5 threes)` -> `sum (take 5 (1:2:3:threes))` -> `sum (1 : take 4 (2:3:threes))` -> `1 + sum (take 4 (2:3:threes))` -> `1 + sum (2 : take 3 (3:threes))`. Notice how I've reduced the top-most node that can be reduced at every step. This is probably what you mean by "Lazy evaluation".

Comment: @user2407038 is this a potential step 1 + 2 + my_sum (my_take 3 (3:first_threes)) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this starts what your teacher wants to see

```
my_sum (my_take 5 first_threes)
-- th.1
my_sum (my_take 5 (1:2:3:first_threes))
-- t.2
my_sum (1 : my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))
-- s.2
1 + my_sum (my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))
-- continue yourself
```

A word on nomenclature: Check whether you have to work through *solutions*. I gave you a few *rewrites*. In every step you use one of the equalities to rewrite your term. The comments indicate which on I used for rewrite..

Answer (score 0):

```
-- original expression
sum (take 5 first_threes)

-- (substitution) apply `take 5 first_threes` to `sum` 
case take 5 first_threes of
  [] -> 0
  (x : xs) -> x + sum xs

-- pattern matching force evaluation of the first cons constructor so
-- we need eval `take 5 first_threes` first

-- apply `first_threes` to `take n` (substitution)
(\ n -> case n of
  0 -> [] 
  _ -> case first_trees of 
         _ -> []
         (x : xs) -> x : take (n - 1) xs) 5

-- apply 5 to the lambda (substitution)
case 5 of
  0 -> [] 
  _ -> case first_trees of 
         _ -> []
         (x : xs) -> x : take (5 - 1) xs

-- 5 is already in normal form, after case analysis we will have
case first_trees of 
  _ -> []
  (x : xs) -> x : take (5 - 1) xs

-- pattern matching again (see above)
case 1 : 2 : 3 : first_threes of
  _ -> []
  (x : xs) -> x : take (5 - 1) xs

-- after case analysis (?) we will have
1 : take (5 - 1) (2 : 3 : first_threes)

-- now we return back to our original expression
case 1 : take (5 - 1) (2 : 3 : first_threes) of
  [] -> 0
  (x : xs) -> x + sum xs

-- after case analysis we will have
1 + sum (take (5 - 1) (2 : 3 : first_threes))

-- (+) operator is strict in both args 
-- the first arg is already evaluated, but we also need to evaluate the second
1 + case take (5 - 1) (2 : 3 : first_threes) of
      [] -> 0
      (x : xs) -> x + sum xs

-- and so on...

-- in the end we will get
1 + (2 + (3 + (1 + (2 + (0)))))
-- which is evaluated in reverse order (starting from the `0`)
```

Comment: @Kamran Are you kidding? You don't know how to add, or... what?